# iOS 6: UserInfo returns nil for Pasteboard change Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nsnotificationcenter, uipasteboard

Here's the Notification Observer for the Pasteboard change event, I need it to handle the copied selected text

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveClipBoardNotification:)
                                             name:@"UIPasteboardChangedNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

And here's the implementation for the selector method **receiveClipBoardNotification:**

```
- (void) receiveClipBoardNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {

//    NSMutableArray *typesAddedKey = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"UIPasteboardChangedTypesAddedKey"];
//    pasteBoardItemType = [typesAddedKey objectAtIndex:0];        

    NSLog(@"%@", [notification userInfo]);
}
```

The problem is that **[notification userInfo]** returns nil on iOS 6, although it works perfectly on iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, This worked on iOS 6

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string]);
```